# How handle return function error in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I'm using PHP to submit a form and then use $.ajax(). Here is my $.ajax method, which works flawlessly when it is successful. When I want to display mistakes, it is difficult to loop over every responseText. See the following $.ajax() code:

```
$.ajax({
// ... ,
error: function(errors){
          $.each(errors, function(index, error){
                info.hide().find('ul').append('<li>'+error+'</li>');
          });
                info.slideDown();
     }
});
```

I detect all problems, but I'm confused about how it displays just errors. See my output on the screen at http://prntscr.com/7nt3lq.
I only want to display the following error fields: If I put it as: "name":["The name field is required."],"fname":["The fname field is required."]

```
error: function(errors){

               console.log(errors);
 }
```

Then the screen output is http://prntscr.com/7nt9tv. With a loop through, how can I eliminate the exceptional error 422 (Unprocessable Entity) and retrieve just the responseText?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the first param to the `error` callback is not the `respose` data, it is the `jqXHR` object.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/echo/asdf',
    // ... ,
    error: function (jqxhr) {
        if (jqxhr.status = 422) {
            var errors = JSON.parse(jqxhr.responseText);
            $.each(errors, function (index, error) {
                info.hide().find('ul').append('<li>' + error + '</li>');
            });
            info.slideDown();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks to reply Arun P Johny. Now it is working, see my screen http://prntscr.com/7ntqi9. In screen I don't want (alert) message in out put and console show error, how control them. thanks again to reply :)

Comment: @saeedahmed I don't think the alert is shown by this code.... the console error we can't do much as the browser is logging it

Comment: But there is still confusion why it rendering (alert) message. you can see it in all shared screens at the top.

Comment: Try to add `info.hide().find('ul').empty()` before `$.each(errors..)`

Comment: Right say! now work fine. :) the console error we can't do much as the browser is logging it, what mean? @Arun P Johny

Comment: Screen see: http://prntscr.com/7nu2k4. if I made a large application the console error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 422 (Unprocessable Entity) do any problem? @Arun P Johny